# iOS - Operation Queues

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

There are a few related threads, but all the searches I’ve done don’t really cover what I’d like to do.

I have an API that has two modes of operation, Sync and Async.

In Sync mode calls to the API MUST be on a background thread and the data is returned to the caller with a possibility that the thread is blocked until the operation has completed.

In Async mode calls to the API may be on a background thread or the Main Thread, a delegate is passed to the API method which returns immediately and the Delegate is called when the operation completes or fails.

This all works, however I have some existing code that I’d like to have the same API and be called by a `Manager Class` which calls the correct underlying API depending on the context, e.g.

AppLayer Calls Manager Class which calls API_A } These APIs have the Same Methods Defined.

AppLayer Calls Manager Class which calls API_B }

API_A is the existing API supporting the Sync/Async interface.
API_B is the one I wish to create.

---

The problem is that the existing code uses `NSOperationQueue`/`NSOperation` accomplish it’s task, this works fine in Async mode. It was easy enough to adapt it to call the Delegate methods, but I’m not sure how to implement Sync mode?

Basically I want to add the NSOperation to the queue and then wait for it to complete before returning with the results.

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated as there seem to be a lot of conflicting advice out there on how to do this and I’ve not been able to find anything that works as described above.

Answer (score 0):

It seems odd that your API specifies that its synchronous mode is... well, dispatched in a different thread than the caller.

That's at least how your question is specified.

It might not be possible to do what you want with the relatively simple NSOperation/NSOperationQueue system. Have you looked into GCD, such as dispatch_once?

Basically, you can't say (in pseudocode)

```
var myval = start_thread_and_do_stuff(a, b, c)
```

The delegate method way is designed to communicate stuff over threads. Since the assignment of myval in that example will happen in a different context, the assignment isn't possible.

Did i read your question the wrong way? In which thread does the method call happen? Background or main thread?